# How to pass dynamic initial values to redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux form in a table, I'm passing **id** as initial value to update some record.

If I pass initial value, it's taking same id to all the rows.

How can I do this ?

```
initialValues: { lead_id: id} //from component


Leads = reduxForm({
    form: `leads`,
    validate,
}))(Leads);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are making `redux-from` for each row of your table component.

You have written:

```
Leads = reduxForm({
    form: `leads`,
    ...,
}))(Leads);
```

You are passing **leads** as value to form prop for all redux-from. You have to give here unique value for each redux-form (corresponding to each row).

You can pass unique id while calling Leads component like this:

```
<Leads form={'your unique id here'} />
```

Comment: Check what is stored in form reducer. Values of each form should be corresponding to unique id passed above.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `connect` to set the intialValues

```
initialValues: { lead_id: id} 


Leads = reduxForm({
    form: `leads`,
    validate,
}))(Leads);


Leads = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: initialValues
  })
)(Leads);
```

Comment: No error. But its taking last id for all the forms.

Comment: The keys in the initialValues object must be the Field names, can you make sure of that

Comment: what do you mean by last id for all the form

Comment: Last record id.